# How to navigate between two navigation Graphs in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, graph, navigation

I have two navigation graphs in my application. The code is as following:

Graph container :

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@+id/main_graph">

 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/HomeFragment"
        android:name="com.test.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/home_login"
            app:destination="@id/login_screen"
            app:popUpTo="@id/HomeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
 </fragment>

 <navigation
        android:id="@+id/settings_id"
        app:startDestination="@+id/SettingsFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentFragment"
            android:name="com.test.SettingsFragment"
            android:label="SettingsFragment">
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_topassword"
                app:destination="@id/password_screen" />
    </fragment> 

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/password_screen"
            android:name="com.test.PasswordFragment"
            android:label="PasswordFragment" />
</navigation>

</navigation>
```

This is the second graph :

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/shows_screen">

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/shows_screen"
        android:name="com.test.ShowsFragment"
        android:label="ShowsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/shows_fragment">
  </fragment>

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/movies_screen"
        android:name="com.test.MoviesFragment"
        android:label="MoviesFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/movies_fragment">
  </fragment>

</navigation>
```

HomeFragment has the tabs which contains the shows and movies tabs. To switch the fragment in the tabs below is the code :

```
val controller =
            activity?.let { Navigation.findNavController(it, R.id.fragmentContainerView) }
        controller?.popBackStack(R.id.home_navigation, true)
val navTabId = R.id.shows_screen
controller?.navigate(navTabId)
```

Now from shows fragment I want to navigate to the settings fragment.
How do I write navigation action for this.
I have tried including the navigation and writing actions but still did not help.
Could you please let me know any feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have to create a global action in the container graph to the navigation settings like this :

```
 <action
        android:id="@+id/action_show_to_settings"
        app:destination="@+id/settings_id"/>
```

This is how the navigation has to be used in the fragments :

```
val mainNavController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),R.id.nav_host_fragment)
 mainNavController.navigate(R.id.action_show_to_settings)
```